# Grails Spring Security Plugin - Where is the plugin directory?

Tags: spring, grails, plugins

I am relatively new to Grails and currently I busy myself with the Spring-Security UI plugin. After reading the documentation I want to make some adjustments at the property file *grails-app/i18n/messages.spring-security-ui.properties*, but I can't find the properties file. Neither in the project-directory, either in the plugins directory.

I have even tried to search it with the unix-command find in my project. (*find . -name 'messages.spring-security-ui.properties'*)

Do I have to use the s2ui-override command to generate the spring-security-ui directory and its properties files?

I have installed the ui-plugin by modifying the BuildConfig.groovy (*compile ":spring-security-ui:0.2"*) and using the command *grails compile*.

Thank you in advance.

Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugins are installed on your local user folder, example:

```
~/.grails/2.0.4/projects/grailsdevs/plugins/
```

where:

```
grailsdevs = project name
```

By the way, you can override the messages properties in your project ones.

check the messages you can use:

http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/25%20Internationalization.html

You don't have to override the plugin because the plugin is installed locally, if you run the app in another computer the plugin will be installed from the repository. So the best way you can do this is add the messages in your i18n resource bundle.

Go to your project... under folder: grails-app/i18n/

Hope this help you

Answer (score 1):

**Don't edit plugin files.**

If you want a different I18N message for a key, add that line to your application's `messages.properties` (and the other locale files if you support multiple languages). The application's files take precedence over plugin files

Just use the same key and whatever message you want to display.